# Wordpress 'wp_insert_post' false positive?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

So I've written a form to accept front-end post creation.

It uses AJAX to deliver the form inputs to a PHP file that returns a string containing the $post_id.

All of this works fine. The AJAX runs, delivers and returns just fine.

The problem is that 'wp_insert_post' is returning a $post_id, but is never actually submitting the post.

The variables and $_POST data below works just fine as well.

```
$post_information = array(
    'post_title' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postTitle'])),
    'post_content' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postHeader'])),
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => $_POST['postStatus'],
    'post_name' => $post_url,
    'post_author' => $post_author
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_information, true);
```

**HAHA. So I done goofed. This site is hosted in a sub-directory of my own site, which also runs WP. The 'wp-load.php' I kept loading for the PHP processor was from the main site...not the subdirectory one. My site now has a bunch of posts created using that form. Developerfail.jpeg**

Comment: So it is not executing the insert, but returns the RIGHT post ID?

Comment: It's returning _A_ Post ID, but no post is created. Its a pretty empty site, so the DB is easily checked directly.

Comment: Thats actually impossible lol, it only returns a Post ID if the query was successfully submitted. Otherwise it returns a wp error object.

Comment: I KNOW RIGHT?! This isn't even the first time I've made a frontend form. Every time I do I have some inexplicable error.

Comment: You have positively confirmed that the row doesn't exist in *_posts?

Comment: You sure that its empty? Maybe only nothing gets displayed on the frontend? Check your database.. (Maybe a wrong hook ?)

Comment: HAHA. So I done goofed.

This site is hosted in a sub-directory of my own site, which also runs WP.

The 'wp-load.php' I kept loading for the PHP processor was from the main site...not the subdirectory one.

My site now has a bunch of posts created using that form.

Developerfail.jpeg

Comment: Leave your question like it is, and write an answer yourself to it. Don't change your "Question" to an Answer..